# SELECT Last x Rows from Table and use last index number of selection (+1) for start of next same query

Tags: mysql

I need to capture last data added to a mysql table in blocks to files every 5 mins (cron)

I need to use last index number as the beginning of next query (+1) .. and so on.

Basically I need to capture blocks of unique records to individual text files with no overlap of records.

I.E.

Index_No     Forename  Surname

1012         bob       Smith

1013         Ann       Smith

1014         Mike      Hope

First run query would get a certain number of events up to 1014.

The next query would run automatically 5 minutes later (cron ?) and start with 1015 upwards.

Etc etc ... every 5 minutes.

I have looked everywhere on www for answer but not yet found one. I am looking specifically for last record from previous query (+1) up to last current entry cycling every 5 minutes.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: lots of files each with block of most recent records in mysql db at the time the queries were made ... with no overlap of records ... essentially snapshots of last 5 minutes of database additions.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I was implementing this requirement, I would write a little program that runs the query and spits the output into a file.  The program would also use some kind of persistant data store (text file/db/whatever) to keep track of the last record.

You can then just use cron to invoke your program.

HTH

Comment: OK .. Thanks. I was leaning in that direction but thought that MYSQL's command / query language might work .. essentially in a 1 liner. :-)

Comment: "select * from db.table_view WHERE HistoryNo > ${LAST_RECORD} ORDER BY HistoryDate asc;" > db-'date+%Y%m%d-%H%M'.log   .... This is what I am trying to achieve, by updating a variable such as "LAST_RECORD" from previous query .. NOTE: syntax may not be correct yet as it is just a guide.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean with looking for the one liner solution - I'm always doing the same! :)  - I don't know of a way the dbms can tell you what rows were last selected - I mean even if it could, what if someone else ran another select in the mean time.  I guess you could modify the schema with some kind of 'recorded' status which you update after running your select - but then you could get concurrency issues where a new row is added just as you're marking things as read etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a log table with index_No and update it with the last No whenever you query. Something like this

```
Create table index_log(Index_no int)

Insert into index_log(Index_no)
select 1014

select columns from source_table
where index_no>(select index_no from index_log)

Update index_log
set index_no=(select max(index_no) from source_table
```